# Navigating to particular screen from FCM callback in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Below is my Push notification manager. I wanted to navigate to particular screens when notification is received when notification is received(when app is in both from background/foreground). Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
class PushNotificationsManager {
PushNotificationsManager._();
factory PushNotificationsManager() => _instance;
static final PushNotificationsManager _instance =
PushNotificationsManager._();

final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
bool _initialized = false;

Future<void> init() async {
if (!_initialized) {
  // For iOS request permission first.
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
  _firebaseMessaging.configure();

  // For testing purposes print the Firebase Messaging token
  String token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
  print("FirebaseMessaging token****: $token");

  _initialized = true;

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onMessage: $message");
      print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");
      print('hi');
      try {
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            navigatorKey.currentContext,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (context) => CategoryListViewModel(),
                child: CategoryListPage(),
              ),
            ),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Exeeee:::" + e.toString());
      }

      print("found");
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onLaunch: $message");
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume: $message");
    },
  );
}
```

}
}

Comment: you need to write in onlaunch for clicks.

Comment: @hasan when I checked further I see the context is null. how get the context in global. I added global key in the main dart file and using still null.

Answer (score 1):

flutter_local_notifications 3.0.2  library can be used to add the notification when the app is in foreground. And this gives an option to navigate to the particular page on clicking of the navigation [library link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/install)

add a global key to keep  the state and use it to get the current context when message is received.

```
 final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Use the key like below.

```
child: MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
```

Declare the below for initialization of firebase

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

And in the init state add the below code

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
_firebaseMessaging.configure();

var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
var initializationSettingsIOs = IOSInitializationSettings();
var initSetttings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOs);

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

// For testing purposes print the Firebase Messaging to

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage@@@: $message");
    String token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print("FirebaseMessaging token****: $token");
    try {
      showNotification();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exeeee:::" + e.toString());
    }
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    PushNotificationsManager.navigationHandler(
        navigatorKey.currentContext, "Test");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    PushNotificationsManager.navigationHandler(
        navigatorKey.currentContext, "Test");
  },
);
}
```

Other two method are used for showing notification when app is in foreground, on click navigation

```
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
try {
  PushNotificationsManager.navigationHandler(
      navigatorKey.currentContext, "Test");
} catch (e) {
  print("Navigation:::" + e.toString());
}
}

showNotification() async {
var android = AndroidNotificationDetails('id', 'channel ', 'description',
    priority: Priority.high, importance: Importance.max);
var ios = IOSNotificationDetails();
var platform = new NotificationDetails(android: android, iOS: ios);
try {
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, 'Flutter devs', 'Flutter Local Notification Demo', platform,
      payload: 'Welcome to the Local Notification demo');
} catch (e) {
  print("Platform Exee:::" + e.toString());
}
}
```

Can write own custom navigation code in the PushNotificationsManager.navigationHandler().

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct but only half way. You'll have to handle when the notification is received on all the other conditions as well if you want it to work when app is open/background/closed. However, in order to navigate, you need the context but doesn't have it. You can use a global key and do it or read this guide [here](https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service/) for easy navigation without context.

Setup a Navigation Service using get_it package as below

```
locator.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
```

get an instance of the service inside your PushNotification Manager like this

```
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
```

then use it to navigate to  your desired screen like this

```
 _navigationService.navigateTo(CreatePostViewRoute);
```

[Here](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/push-notifications-in-flutter-using-firebase/) is their guide on push notification handling
Super easy and works right out of the box

Comment: please check my answer navigator key is used in gloabal. I am getting current context from the navigator key.

Comment: Probably means that the key is null when you try to use it for navigation. Can you show the code where you declare the key ?